# MQTT recv from a publish and mqtt ping C

Tags: c, sockets, recv, mqtt

i've got this problem, in a test program, where i'm developing a client for MQTT, i'm subscribed on a topic, after that, i wait for "publish" message from the server to my client.

After a good recv (of a publish message) or after a recv timeout i send a mqtt PINGREQ to the server.

After a A PINGREQ i'm going to wait a PINGRESP, then i call a recv as in the case I were waiting for a PUBLISH message.

If the flow is this:

```
Client -> PINGREQ
Server -> PUBLISH
Server -> PINGRESP
```

Than the server publish message were lost. How to solve this? I'm using MQTT at QOS 0, it make sense solve this problem on this level of QOS or instead is smart to check this case at QOS1?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got things a bit confused. PINGREQ/PINGRESP are used when there isn't any other network traffic passing between the client and server, in order to let both the client and server know if the connection drops.

Your client should keep track of the when the last outgoing or incoming communication with the server was, and send a PINGREQ if it is going to exceed the keepalive timer it set with its CONNECT command. The server will disconnect the client at 1.5*keepalive if no communication is received. The client should assume the server has been disconnected if it does not receive a PINGRESP in response to its PINGREQ within keepalive of sending the PINGREQ.

The QoS level isn't that important, you have to ensure the keepalive timeout is maintained regardless.

It also occurs to me that it sounds like you're using blocking network calls - it might be best to move to non-blocking if you can to get more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, i'm moving to non-blocking calls. In this way, there is small possibilities that my client is in recv for a PINGREQ and there is a PUBLISH incoming, right?.This is the benefit?

Comment: I'm now testing to publish more data with no ping during reception after that all data is arrived, server seems to close connection. Seems that the timer is not reset when a publish from the server to the client is made.

Comment: Non-blocking calls have the significant advantage that you don't have to wait until incoming data arrives once you have made the call to recv().

Comment: The server expects network communication from the client to reset the timer, this is the way it knows if the client is there. Sending data to the client tells it nothing unless there is a reply unfortunately, so you do need to send a PINGREQ every keepalive seconds if you are only receiving data from the server.

Comment: Another thought - is there any reason why you can't use one of the existing client libraries?

Comment: i'm developing it on an embedded system, this one http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/matchport-bg-pro.html